# Sort by one criteria and have another to fall back on

Tags: views

I'm trying to configure a view (using the Views module) that sorts the content by content weight, then by total content views (loading a max of 6 items).

For a quick explanation, this is to list the most popular 'resources' on the resources page (PDFs). I'd like the list to be sorted by total views, which I've already achieved. However, I want to be able to give a weight to specific resources (resource is a content type, I've created a weight field using a simple list(integer) field that goes from -3 to 3) which the 'Popular Resources' view sorts by first before loading by total views.

I've tried giving the view 2 sort criteria, which are:

- Content: Most Popular Resources Block Weight (asc)
- Content statistics: Total views (desc)

I have 1 resource with a popular resource block weight set (the rest don't have a weight set), but the view isn't showing this resource as it has a lower number of total views than the others being loaded.

If possible I'd like the view to sort by resources that have a weight set, then when it runs out of blocks that have a weight, use total views to load and sort the rest of the resources. I've tried looking for a way to do this but haven't found anything yet.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the issue. The resources that didn't have a weight set were treated as having a lower weight than ones that did. I changed the weighting to sort by descending, which is the opposite of how weight should work, but seems to be the only solution.